# CoreData multithreading fetch requires small delay before accessing attributes

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I use coreData as persistent store.
To read data, I use (only essential parts are shown):

```
func fetchShoppingItems(completion: @escaping (Set<ShoppingItem>?, Error?) -> Void) {
    persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (backgroundManagedContext) in
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CDShoppingItem> = CDShoppingItem.fetchRequest()
        var shoppingItems: Set<ShoppingItem> = []
        do {
            let cdShoppingItems: [CDShoppingItem] = try backgroundManagedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for nextCdShoppingItem in cdShoppingItems {
                nextCdShoppingItem.managedObjectContext!.performAndWait {
                    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1) // This seems to be required
                    let nextShoppingItem = ShoppingItem.init(name: nextCdShoppingItem.name!)
                    shoppingItems.insert(nextShoppingItem)
                } // performAndWait
            } // for all cdShoppingItems
            completion(shoppingItems, nil)
            return
        } catch let error as NSError {
            completion(nil, error)
            return
        } // fetch error
    } // performBackgroundTask
} // fetchShoppingItems
```

To test the coreData implementation, I wrote a unit test that creates multiple threads that write to and read from coreData concurrently.
This test runs only successfully, if the instruction

```
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1) // This seems to be required
```

is inserted in the `performAndWait` closure.
If it is commented out, `nextCdShoppingItem` is often read back with `nil` attributes, and the function crashes due to the forced unwrap.
I am not sure, if `nextCdShoppingItem.managedObjectContext!.performAndWait` is correct or if I had to use `backgroundManagedContext.performAndWait`, but with `backgroundManagedContext` the effect is the same.
I do not understand why inserting a small delay before accessing an attribute of a managed object is necessary to avoid the problem.
Any hint is welcome!

**EDIT:**

I investigated the issue further, and found the following:

Every time `nextCdShoppingItem` is read back by the background thread (called read thread below) as `nil`, there is also another background thread that tries to save its own managedContext after all records in its managedContext have been deleted (called write thread below).
Apparently the read thread tries to fetch a record that has just been deleted by the write thread.
So the problem is definitively a multithreading issue, and I found a solution (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent the multithreading issue, I tried 2 things:

1) Since iOS10, a persistentStore of SQL type maintains a connection pool for concurrent access to the pool, and it is possible to set a maximum pool size, see [the WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/242/?time=1131). I did so using

```
private lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: modelName)
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // ...
        } else {
            storeDescription.setOption(NSNumber(1), forKey: NSPersistentStoreConnectionPoolMaxSizeKey)
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

to prevent concurrent access to the persistentStore. Unfortunately, this did not solve the problem for an unknown reason.

2) I then tried to serialize read and write operations by setting up a serial queue:

```
private let coreDataSerialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.xxx.ShopEasy.coreDataManager") // serial by default
```

It is used for the read and write accesses in the following way:

```
coreDataSerialQueue.async {
    let backgroundManagedContext = self.persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    backgroundManagedContext.performAndWait {
        // …
    } // performAndWait
} // coreDataSerialQueue.async
```

**This did solve the problem.**

Please note that **it would be wrong** to use

```
coreDataSerialQueue.async {
    self.persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (backgroundManagedContext) in
        // …
    } // performBackgroundTask
} // coreDataSerialQueue.async
```

because `performBackgroundTask` would fork another asynchronous thread and thus break the serialization.

Comment: Sorry, it is linked now. See it at 18:58.

Answer (score 0):

performAndWait will add the block to the queue and schedule it to run, just like perform, but performAndWait will not return until the block is complete.  Since you are inside a loop of `cdShoppingItems`, the loop does not stop and wait for the block to return.  By adding the thread sleep, you are essentially slowing down the loop and giving core data enough time to complete its fetch.   The forced unwrap crash is probably an indication that it's lost its nextCdShoppingItem reference.

I would consider refactoring where you do not need to query core data inside a loop.  If it's possible, add the `name` attribute to CDShoppingItem so you don't have to fetch it to build a ShoppingItem object.

Edit: took a stab at a refactor although I don't know your exact use case:

```
func fetchShoppingItems(completion: @escaping (Set<ShoppingItem>?, Error?) -> Void) {
    persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { (backgroundManagedContext) in
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<CDShoppingItem> = CDShoppingItem.fetchRequest()
        do {
            var shoppingItems: Set<ShoppingItem> = []
            let cdShoppingItems: [CDShoppingItem] = try backgroundManagedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            for nextCdShoppingItem in cdShoppingItems {
                if let name = nextCdShoppingItem.name {
                    let nextShoppingItem = ShoppingItem.init(name: name)
                    shoppingItems.insert(nextShoppingItem)
                }
            }
            completion(shoppingItems, nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error fetching CDShoppingItem: \(error)")
            completion(nil, error)
        } // fetch error
        return
    } // performBackgroundTask
} // fetchShoppingItems
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Essentially, you suggest to remove `performAndWait`, and insert `nextShoppingItem` only if `name` is not `nil`. Now the conditional insert avoids the crash, but it does not help since `name` cannot be `nil`, except in the error case. And if I execute the code with force unwrapping `name`, it behaves exactly the same: With the delay it works, without, it crashes.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your intentions.  By inserting only cdShoppingItems that name is not nil, you shouldn't have to force unwrap it when initializing a ShoppingItem.  There seems to a concurrency issue somewhere in the mix if a delay works.  Also, I missed the catch in my code so I updated it.